# With a routing model, how do I break up the input locations into start/end pairs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have the following model:
[image]

How do I break up the feature set of points (Input Locations) into start/end pairs, and iterate through each pair

Comment: Would you consider switching to arcpy Python scripting? It might be way easier to do then.

Comment: I need to create a gpk from running the model.  I don't know arcpy Python, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to have a column in your input feature class which will represent the RouteName (i.e., feature1 and feature2 belong to routeA; feature3 and feature4 belong to routeB and so on).

After you've prepared the input feature class (or maybe you already have one), you would need to use the [Add Locations GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Add_Locations/004800000005000000/) to load the stops into an existing Route network analysis layer (RouteLayer in your model). The parameter you are interested in is `field_mappings`. In the Field column, choose what field should Network Analyst look for.

[image]

You can do the same from Python, for instance:

```
arcpy.na.AddLocations(RouteLayer, "Stops", input_fc,
                        "Name PointName #; RouteName MyRouteNameColumn #",
                        exclude_restricted_elements="EXCLUDE")
```

So you need to load all your stops just once in a model (no need to iterate anything). Your stops will be loaded with assigned RouteName to them and solved pair wise.

[image]

And after solving:

[image]